# How do I create a ruby class that is initialized with and array with the properties of a string and an integer?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I am trying to create a ruby class that is initialized with an array of products with the
properties of `name[String]` and `rating[Integer]`. I have not done straight ruby in a while and I am stumped.

I want instances of this class to be able to

- Responding with the highest rated product
- Determining the average rating of all the products
- Printing a list of the 10 most highly rated products to STDOUT

The goal would also be to script it but I remember how to do that. Just need advice on how to set up the class.

Comment: Your question seems to contain multiple topics (class syntax, initialization, determine max / average from a collection, printing to stdout) – that makes it harder to write a succinct answer. Try to have one topic per question. It also helps a lot if you show your code, even if it is incomplete / not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set up a class with the `initialize` method that will assign the provided array of products:

```rb
class ProductStats
  def initialize(products)
    @products = products
  end
end
```

From there you can create instance methods on the class to get the highest rated product, average rating, and any other methods you need:

```rb
class ProductStats
  def initialize(products)
    @products = products
  end

  def highest_rated
    @products.max_by { |product| product[:rating] }
  end
end
```

You can then initialize an instance with your products:

```rb
product_stats = ProductStats.new([
  { name: "Socks", rating: 1 },
  { name: "Jacket", rating: 2 },
  { name: "Hat", rating: 3 }
])

product_stats.highest_rated
# => { :name=>"Hat", :rating=>3 }
```

For demonstration purposes, this assumes that a "product" is a simple Hash object, but the same core principles apply if a product is an instance of a different class (e.g. `Product` or similar).

Comment: That should be `max_by`. And Instead of using a hash, you could write a small `Product` class with actual attributes so you can `max_by(&:rating)`

Comment: Definitely over thinking this! Thank you!

Comment: @Stefan Good catch on `max_by`, updated answer to use it.

Comment: Do you think I can use .sum for the average?

Comment: @JozyKinnaman You should be able to use sum there (e.g. `@products.sum / @products.size.to_f`).